# Use listagg result in WHERE clause of other SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a LISTAAGG RESULT

```
SELECT LISTAGG(TO_NUMBER(ORG_IDORGA), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORG_IDORGA) listaid FROM SGP_ORGA WHERE ORG_IDORGA_P = 201
```

The result is an string (201,202,203)

I want to use this result in the where clause of my next select. The problem is the new field im filtering from is a number.

`Select * From tabla2 where fieldNumber in resultStringFromListAgg;`

Answer (score 1):

That's a wrong approach. Why would you first aggregate some values and then worry about extracting them to format that's suitable to be used in an `IN` list?

What you need is just an ordinary join:

```
select b.* 
from tabla2 b join sgp_orga s on s.org_idorga = b.fieldnumber
where s.org_idorg_p = 201
```

Comment: It certainly is.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare

V_SQL   varchar2(2000 char);
V_SQL1   varchar2(2000 char);
V_SQL2   varchar2(2000 char);

begin

V_SQL := '
SELECT LISTAGG(TO_NUMBER(ORG_IDORGA), '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORG_IDORGA) 
listaid FROM SGP_ORGA WHERE ORG_IDORGA_P = 201';

V_SQL1 := 'Select * From tabla2 ';

 
V_SQL2 :=  V_SQL1 || ' where fieldNumber in (' || V_SQL || ' ) ';

V_SQL2;

end;
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanations to your answer?